# Using document.querySelectorALL in multiple queries to add/remove classes

Tags: javascript

I am writing JS code for a modal. I am very new to JS. Is there a way to combine these two blocks of code? I am using this JS to add and remove classes.

I tried using querySelectorALL but only first query worked.

```
  document.querySelector('#open-modal1').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var modal = document.querySelector('#myModal1');  
  var html = document.querySelector('html');
  modal.classList.add('is-active');
  html.classList.add('is-clipped');

    modal.querySelector('.modal-background').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal.classList.remove('is-active');
    html.classList.remove('is-clipped');
  });

    modal.querySelector('.bulma-modal-close').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal.classList.remove('is-active');
    html.classList.remove('is-clipped');
  });  

});

  document.querySelector('#open-modal2').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var modal = document.querySelector('#myModal2');  
  var html = document.querySelector('html');
  modal.classList.add('is-active');
  html.classList.add('is-clipped');  

    modal.querySelector('.modal-background').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal.classList.remove('is-active');
    html.classList.remove('is-clipped');
  });

    modal.querySelector('.bulma-modal-close').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal.classList.remove('is-active');
    html.classList.remove('is-clipped');
  }); 

});
```

open-modal1 should operate on #myModal1
open-modal2 should operate on #myModal2 and so on.
Also the 2 queries which remove classes can be common throughout?

Html Code -

```html
<div class="modal" id="myModal1">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-card">
    <header class="modal-card-head">
      <p class="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
      <button class="delete bulma-modal-close"></button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-card-body">
      <p>There is something here</p>
    </section>
    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
      <button class="button">Ok</button>
      <button class="button bulma-modal-close">Cancel</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the link that opens above modal -

```html
<a class="button" id="open-modal1" href="">Open modal</a>
```

Comment: You need to loop over the elements that querySelectorAll returns, and assign the event handler to each element individually.

Comment: could you add your `HTML` code along with trying to explain more ? Also, I don't see any call for `querySelectorAll` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
document.querySelector('#open-modal1').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    styleModal(event, "#myModal1");
});

document.querySelector('#open-modal2').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    styleModal(event, "#myModal2");
});

function styleModal(event, myModal) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var modal = document.querySelector(myModal);
    var html = document.querySelector('html');
    modal.classList.add('is-active');
    html.classList.add('is-clipped');

    modal.querySelector('.modal-background').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        modal.classList.remove('is-active');
        html.classList.remove('is-clipped');
    });

    modal.querySelector('.bulma-modal-close').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        modal.classList.remove('is-active');
        html.classList.remove('is-clipped');
    });
}


//if you are wanting to execute both on a loop...
var myModals = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='myModal']");

for(var i = 0; i < myModals.length; i++){
    styleModal(myModals[i].id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So I can write multiple queries above with a common function. Can you explain what the last part does please? Thanks again :)

Comment: The last part is actually probably incomplete when looking at it a second time. You don't need it you just stick with the first part. It demonstrates finding all of the elements that have an id beginning with "myModal", looping through them, and executing a function against them. But it doesn't account for the individual triggers that need to fire.

Comment: And yes, modular programming is always the right way to go! You may consider challenging yourself to make this more modular.